# How can I add a horizontal line into chart control?

Tags: c#, charts

I have `Chart Control` that received real data and i want to add this horizontal line in order to calculate average value.

Comment: you need to improve this question, include a lot more detail about what char control, wpf, winforms, asp.net, etc etc. And what you have already tried

Comment: How does a horizontal line calculate an average? Please improve your question.

Comment: User @ Derek W: The Straight line will calculate the average traffic according number of point currently in the chart

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add horizontal line to chart in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21990022/add-horizontal-line-to-chart-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a constant horizontal line, you can add a [Stripline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.stripline.aspx). If you have DevExpress controls they make this simple with the ConstantLine object.

Comment: Can i have an code example how to do that ? (i am a new developer)

Comment: Or add a LineAnnotation